# Is there a way to selectively sync files/folders in iCloud Drive?

Tags: itunes, icloud, applications, backup, storage

I have a 2TB iCloud storage plan and I'd like to upload a media folder for backup purposes onto Apple's servers without having it automatically download to iCloud Drive on my local SSD.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I don't want to "optimize" storage, I just want to selectively (not) sync a folder.

Comment: OneDrive allows you to do this.

Comment: I have a small utility that can evict or download items at request: https://github.com/ezfe/iCloud-Manager ; It has no logic and just calls system calls to perform those actions, but should achieve your goal (if not permanently)